# Handwriting or handwritten text recognition in augmented reality

Tags: unity, c#

Is there any way available to detect **handwriting of a user** using augmented reality within Unity. Or convert user hand written text into characters?

Comment: What is your input method? How are you getting this handwritten image? Is the user writing digitally, or is the input an image? You need to look into OCR libraries for this, but your question is incredibly broad.

Comment: This really isn't relevant to game development IMO. There's standard libraries (quick google brought up http://myscript.com/ and other and even some stackoverflow questions) that do this. You'd just need to capture some path data from the user drawing in the air (and probably transform it to make it flat) and then plug it into a library like this.

Comment: @ext0 I guess in aumgented reality its utilized computer vision concepts ? so basically it will use computer vision algorithm to extract the writing charachter. this is what i am asking

Comment: @Coburn "capture some path data from the user drawing in the air" this is what i am asking in unity3d with AR.

Comment: @PatrickBell input method is handwriting image.

Answer (score 1):

You're asking an extremely broad question considering there are so many specific design decisions that relate not only to your application but also the hardware you'll want to use. *Augmented reality* is really broad considering it can apply to anything from VR Headsets, to things like the Kinect, to even phones. You'll probably get more helpful answers if there's a specific point that you're having trouble with but from what you asked there can only be broad answers. The entire task from sensor input to alpha-numeric characters can be broken down into two parts.

1. Capture input handwriting data
2. Put input handwriting data into library

### Capture Input Handwriting Data

Requirements to track handwriting data will be

- Determine when the user wants to start
- Determine the actual path the user is drawing
- Determine when the user "picks up pen" while writing
- Determine when the user wants to stop

*Possible solution 1: A button* - The most intuitive way to solve this problem would be to give the user some sort of button (like in the HTC Vive, Oculus Touch, etc). You might have to provide the user with a button if you're using something else (Leap Motion, Xbox Kinect). The use would then draw within the space of the motion tracking camera while holding the button.

The button would delineate between a writing and non-writing mode so that users could determine when they want to start, stop, and break up words. Motion tracking would take care of the actual path the user is drawing.

*Possible solution 2: A box* - Another way you might solve this would be to have a distance from the augmented reality camera or interaction with a physical surface on a virtual level be the start and stop writing action. Similar to how you interact with a signature pad at a point of sale system, pressing "into" (in this case beyond) the surface would trigger writing while pulling back would stop writing.

There's probably other solutions that more creative people will come up with but these are the most obvious to me.

### Put input handwriting data into library

From the previous step we can assume that we get a list of vector paths that each represent portions of the handwriting. You'd have to then transform this data to put it into the handwriting library.

This might include (again, hardware and application specific):

- Flipping the data horizontally depending on the direction your camera is facing relative to the user.
- Transform your input data so that it lays on a flat plane as a handwriting library would expected (either disregarding the cameras view vector axis or treating the text as mapped onto a cylinder perpendicular with the up direction to remove any 3 space curvature from the text)
- Breaking up the pathing data into discrete units so the handwriting library can work its magic.

You could then shove the new data into your glyph/writing recognition library from which you have multiple choices (from a quick google search).

- http://myscript.com/
- http://www.phatware.com/index.php?q=page/writepadsdk/ios
- http://handwriting-sdk.com/
- https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms749012(v=vs.110).aspx
- https://sourceforge.net/directory/graphics/graphics/handrec/os:windows/

And from the many choices above, you would get some sort of string representations of what was written.